# String to array nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I format a string (I can format the string in any way)

e.g

```
   id1:234,id2:4566,id3:3000
```

then encrypt it and pass via query string

```
   ?qs=djdjdjfjf57577574h33h3h3hh3h3
```

then decrypt it on node

```
   id1:234,id2:4566,id3:3000
```

which is the best method to format the string and then turn it into an array in node

```
    arr[id1] = "234";
    arr[id2] = "4566";
    arr[id3] = "3000";
```

Comment: can I ask what is the context for this solution? What are you doing with it?

Comment: pass argument from php site to a node soket

Comment: What are `id1`, `id2` and `id3` supposed to be in your example? They are not variables, but string literals right?

Comment: yes because I encrypt and decript a string for security,I do not want to pass values ​​that can be haked

Comment: That example is so close to JSON that for me is the obvious next step to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, what you have as your object model is more of a hash like object or simply a JavaScript object with keys and values, so the best way to do that is simply using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

So if you can do it as you said: I can format the string in any way, you better first change your formatting to have something like:

```
'{"id1":234,"id2":4566,"id3":3000}'
```

instead of :

```
id1:234,id2:4566,id3:3000
```

you can do it using `JSON.stringify` on the client side JavaScript using a JavaScript object without you needing to deal with string formatting:

```
//on the client side
var myObj = {};
myObj.id1 = 234;
myObj.id2 = 4566;
myObj.id3 = 3000;
var objStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

let's say you encrypt your string using a function named `encrypt`:

```
var encryptedStr = encrypt(objStr);
//so now you should use encodeURI to be able to put it in the queryString
var queryStringParam = encodeURI(encryptedStr);
```

now you put the `queryStringParam` in the queryString.

Then on the node.js side, all you should do is parsing it as a JSON object. The other important point that you probably have considered doing it is using `decodeURI`. For the last step, let's say you are using e function named `decrypt`:

```
//the server-side code
var decryptedStr = decrypt(decodeURI(yourQueryString));
var obj = JSON.parse(decryptedStr);
```

Now obj is exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks It works! but if i put the client side part is useless to encrypt the string ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you would like to use hashmap (object) instead of array:
`var obj = {}`
then try:

```
"id1:234,id2:4566,id3:3000".split(",").forEach(function(e){
    var record = e.split(":");
    obj[record[0]] = record[1];
})
```

which give you:
`{id1: "234", id2: "4566", id3: "3000"}`

Comment: There is no `each` function. You can use `forEach`, but this is not supported for <IE8.

Comment: It will be on NodeJS side, I assumed there is `"each"` since on Chrome there is :)

Comment: There is no `each` function as far as I can tell

Comment: @Amberlamps edited, thanks (seems to site on which I ran console has that method in array).